# Comando GIT para contar coincidencias en todos los archivos

Tags: git

Estoy buscando un comando GIT que me permita encontrar las coincidencias para una palabra determinada en todos los archivos, pero filtrados según un autor específico.

Lo que más se aproxima es "git grep", pero no consigo hacer que funcione con el filtro para un autor.

Ejemplo:

```
git grep --count 'TODO'
```

Eso me devuelve la cuenta correcta en cada archivo que contiene la palabra 'TODO', pero no sé cómo restringirla por autor. Probé diferentes variantes como "--author=", pero no funcionan.

Comment: Nota que -en el contexto de git- el autor es un atributo del commit, mas no del archivo. De tal manera que no sabemos si buscas por el autor del commit donde se introdujo el archivo en el repositorio, o el autor del commit del estado actual (o un estado anterior) del archivo.

Comment: Claro, lo que yo busco es en el estado actual, en el contenido del proyecto, indiferentemente del commit. Ahora entiendo que si es un atributo del commit, no voy a poder especificar el autor en este tipo de búsqueda, a no ser que se puedan combinar ambos criterios.

Comment: Git cuenta con un comando llamado [`grep`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2929502/13419694) habría que investigar cómo se usa y ver si te sirve.

Answer (score 2):

Es muy frecuente en *NIX conectar comandos con *tuberías* (`pipes` en inglés) para obtener resultados que cada uno de los comandos no podría generar por separado. Podrías conectar un listado de archivos (con `git ls-tree`) con un `git blame` y luego grep para filtrar el autor y el texto. Algo como esto:

```
git ls-tree -r HEAD | while read archivo; do
  echo "$archivo": $( git blame -w "$archivo" | grep "fulanito de tal" | grep "un patron de texto" | wc -l )
done
```

Cada blame toma algo de tiempo, dependiendo del tamaño de la historia de cada archivo así que ten paciencia si el proyecto es muy grande.

Esto lo estoy haciendo "de memoria" (estoy en el celular) así que puede ser que se me escape algún detalle pero la idea general debe funcionar.